# Select an aggregate column from 2 views

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two query for views:

First view:

```
SELECT 
   t1.entity_id, t1.entity_name, 
   t2.order1, t2.order2, t2.order3, t2.order4, t3.date, t2.score
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.code = t3.code
WHERE 
   t1.entity_id = 1
```

Second view:

```
SELECT 
   t1.entity_id, t1.entity_name, 
   t2.order1, t2.order2, t2.order3, t2.order4, max(t3.date) as 'date'
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.code = t3.code
WHERE
   t1.entity_id = 1
GROUP BY 
   t1.entity_id, t1.entity_name, t2.order4, t2.order3, t2.order2, t2.order1
```

The problem that come to me is when I'm trying to select the final score with the max date, it comes with the error:

> *Column 'dbo.t2.score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

I'm stuck to get the score with the latest date without using any aggregate for the score. I've tried so many ways but I couldn't figure it out to get the score with the latest date 
How do I get the score with this condition (after checking order1 to order4 when it's the same):

- When the date is different, pick the latest score
- When the date is same, pick the max score

Is it possible to do that?

How can I get the `entity_id` and `score` with the condition above?

### UPDATE

The result of view1:

```
entity_id | entity_name | order1 | order2 | order3 | order4 | date       | score
================================================================================  
1         | entity 1    | aaa    | rrr    | eee    | NULL   | 2012-12-15 | 2  
1         | entity 1    | aaa    | rrr    | eee    | NULL   | 2012-11-01 | 5.3  
1         | entity 1    | bbb    | sss    | ttt    | ggg    | 2012-11-16 | 1.5  
1         | entity 1    | ccc    | sss    | xxx    | NULL   | 2012-12-15 | 2.3
```

The result of view2:

```
entity_id | entity_name | order1 | order2 | order3 | order4 | date
========================================================================
1         | entity 1    | aaa    | rrr    | eee    | NULL   | 2012-12-15 
1         | entity 1    | bbb    | sss    | ttt    | ggg    | 2012-11-16
1         | entity 1    | ccc    | sss    | xxx    | NULL   | 2012-12-15
```

The result I want:

```
entity_id | entity_name | order1 | order2 | order3 | order4 | date       | score
================================================================================  
1         | entity 1    | aaa    | rrr    | eee    | NULL   | 2012-12-15 | 2  
1         | entity 1    | bbb    | sss    | ttt    | ggg    | 2012-11-16 | 1.5  
1         | entity 1    | ccc    | sss    | xxx    | NULL   | 2012-12-15 | 2.3
```

I have resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First: there is a small error in the column selected in the second query (3 times t2.order2).

Second, part of the answer:

```
SELECT 
    t1.entity_id, t1.entity_name, t2.order4, t2.order3, t2.order2, t2.order1, t2.score, max(t3.date) as 'date'
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.code = t3.code
WHERE
   t1.entity_id = 1
GROUP BY 
    t1.entity_id, t1.entity_name, t2.order4, t2.order3, t2.order2, t2.order1, t2.score
```

If I understand properly, you just want a result for each score, then you just have to add the score column to the select part and also in the group by part.

Remember: in SQL-Server and also in Oracle, you have to put column in the group by clause if you want to display it without operation (max, first, sum, etc...).

Comment: I've tried your query and it can't solve my problems but thanks anyway. I remember the rules of grouping and aggregate.  I've updated my question.  Well I wanna put the table result but I don't know how to do it since I'm new here. But thanks

Comment: It would help if you can put some data extract and what result you want. For me it does not look so difficult but I cannot really see  what you are trying to do.

Comment: how can I extract the data and the result? Sorry

Comment: I mean not to put the exact data but an extract of each table you manually write with only the few columns you have to calculate and what is the expected result.